# Паттерны Poor Man's DI и Bastard Injection

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Наткнулся в сети на комментарий, в котором упоминались паттерны Poor Man's DI и Bastard Injection -- что это такое и в чём между ними разница?

(Любой язык программирования, не обязательно c#)

Comment: Упомяну свежую тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787125/213987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Poor Man's DI**, также называемое **Pure DI** - это DI без специальной библиотеки-контейнера. В случае использования такого подхода все зависимости классов выносятся в параметры их конструкторов либо в свойства, причем все классы, конструкторы и свойства обязаны быть открытыми. Пример на C#:

```
public class Baz
{
    private readonly IBar bar;
    public Baz(IBar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

В Composition Root же пишется код, который собирает все эти классы вместе - то есть весь граф объектов собирается вручную. Код получается вроде вот такого:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar(foo);

SomeFrameworkClass.SetControllerFactory(() => { // точка входа
    var baz = new Baz(bar);
    return new Controller(foo, baz);
});
```

В чистом виде Pure DI используется редко, однако если ваши классы написаны с использованием Pure DI-подхода, то к проекту можно прикрутить любую библиотеку-контейнер, или же сменить ее в любой момент.

---

**Bastard Injection** же - это полная противоположность прошлому подходу. В случае использования Bastard Injection каждый класс самостоятельно затягивает свои зависимости из контейнера используя его как Service Locator:

```
public class Baz
{
    private readonly IBar bar = App.container.Resolve<IBar>();
}
```

Главный недостаток такого подхода - зависимости оказываются раскиданы по коду. К примеру, без доступа к исходникам единственный способ определить какие зависимости нужны классу `Baz` - это вызвать его конструктор и посмотреть на отсутствие чего он ругнется. А уж опциональные зависимости без документации найти можно только декомпиляцией.

Comment: А, Poor Man's DI -- этот синоним обычной DI через конструктор, как её пишут в разных учебных материалах. Зря только название такое отталкивающее. Bastard Injection -- реально антипаттерн.

Comment: @AK не совсем. Poor Man's/Pure DI - это когда контейнера нет вообще, не только в классах - но и в Composition Root. Это - мысленная конструкция, которая используется для демонстрации свойств некоторых подходов.