# C# WinForms. DI Autofac. Управление временем жизни зависимости переданной в форму

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Здравствуйте, один из проектов потребителей бизнес логики это старый UI проект на WinForms, он  подвергся рефакторингу, и нужно внедрить DI autofac.
Я так понял рекомедуется регистрирвоать создание самой формы тоже через контейнер, но тогда как управлять временем жизни зависимостями формы? Хочу контролировать вызов Dispouse зависимостей.

Регистрация:

```
private static void RegisterType(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<MyLogger>().As<ILogger>();  //MyLogger принимает в конструкторе IWriter
    builder.RegisterType<SimpleWriter>().As<IWriter>();
    builder.RegisterType<LogForm>();
}
```

Предположим внутри MainForm по событию кнопки нужно открыть LogForm и передать туда зависимость ILogger.

```
public LogForm(ILogger logger)
{
    Logger = logger;
    InitializeComponent();
}

LogForm можно создать через резолв контейнера (т.к. весь граф ее зависимостей зарегистрирован).
Как лучше создать LogForm?
```

### Вариант 1

```
private void btn_OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var scope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
       var logForm = scope.Resolve<LogForm>();
       logForm.Show();
    }
}
```

scope управляет временем жизни всех разрезолвенных объектов, поэтому сразу при открытии формы будет вызван Dispose у вложенных сервисов (SimpleWriter и MyLogger).
Если только это не блокирующий вызов диалоговой формы (logForm.ShowDialog), тогда все отработает верно и при закрытии формы вызовется Dispose.

### Вариант 2

```
private void btn_OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  var logForm = AutofacConfig.Container.Resolve<LogForm>();
  logForm.Show();       
}
```

Без объекта scope резолвим зависимость и полагаемся на уничтожение зависимостей контейнером.
Наверно не правильно)).

### Вариант 3

```
private readonly ILifetimeScope _lfScope; 
private void btn_OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _lfScope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())   
      var logForm = _lfScope.Resolve<LogForm>();
      logForm.Show();   
}
```

Выносим из using scope и вызываем на нем Dispouse когда нам нужно.
Но как то странно в родительской форме отслеживать когда закроется дочерняя и вызвать в событии _lfScope.Dispouse.

### Вариант 4

```
private void btn_OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var logForm = new LogForm();//Создавать без DI и зависимостей.
    logForm.Show();
}

//Изменим класс формы LogForm
public partial class LogForm : Form
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }            //Сервис
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lfScope;      //Управление временем жизни сервиса

    public LogForm() 
    {
     _lfScope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope(); 
     Logger = _lfScope.Resolve<ILogger>();

     InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //............
    }


    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        _lfScope.Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

В конструктор формы не передаем зависимости  и создаем форму без DI.
В конструкторе формы получаем scope и резолвим сервис. 
При закрытии формы очищаем ресурсы.

Вариант 4 кажется наиболее логичным.
Подскажите как лучше?

Регистрация нескольких ILogger для LogForm

```
builder.RegisterType<NyLogger>().Named<ILogger>("11").InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 

builder.RegisterType<OtherLogger>().Named<ILogger>("22").InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 

 builder.RegisterType<LogForm>()
  .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
      (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
       (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ILogger>("11")
       )).InstancePerDependency();
```

// Попытка разрезолвить сразу 2 именованные зависимости.

```
public partial class DoubleLogForm : Form
{
    public ILogger Logger1 { get; set; }            //Сервис
    public ILogger Logger2 { get; set; }            //Сервис
    private readonly IDisposable _loggerOwner1;
    private readonly IDisposable _loggerOwner2;

    public DoubleLogForm(Owned<ILogger> logger1, Owned<ILogger> logger2) 
    {
        Logger1 = logger1.Value;
        _loggerOwner1 = logger1;

        Logger2 = logger2.Value;
        _loggerOwner2 = logger2;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }


    builder.RegisterType<NyLogger>().Named<ILogger>("NyLogger").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<OtherLogger>().Named<ILogger>("OtherLogger").InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<DoubleLogForm>()
        .WithParameters(new List<ResolvedParameter> {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Owned<ILogger>),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<Owned<ILogger>>("NyLogger")),
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Owned<ILogger>),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<Owned<ILogger>>("OtherLogger"))
        }).InstancePerDependency();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все 4 варианта - неправильны! Любое прямое обращение к контейнеру за пределами Composition Root (в вашем случае это, наверное, метод Main) - это антипаттерн Bastard Injection.

Для ситуаций когда компонент должен управлять временем жизни своих зависимостей, в Autofac придумали обертку `Owned`. С ее использованием дочерняя форма будет выглядеть вот так:

```
public partial class LogForm : Form
{
    private readonly Owned<ILogger> Logger;

    public LogForm(Owned<ILogger> logger)
    {
        this.Logger = logger;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Доступ к логгеру - через `Logger.Value`. Если лень переписывать кучу кода, которая уже обращается к нему напрямую - никто не запрещает вытащить `logger.Value` в конструкторе:

```
public partial class LogForm : Form
{
    private readonly ILogger Logger;
    private readonly IDisposable LoggerOwner;

    public LogForm(Owned<ILogger> logger)
    {
        this.Logger = logger.Value;
        this.LoggerOwner = logger;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        LoggerOwner.Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Теперь про создание формы. Создавать новые объекты нужно через фабрику:

```
private readonly Func<LogForm> logFormFactory;

public MainForm(Func<LogForm> logFormFactory)
{
    this.logFormFactory = logFormFactory;
}

private void btn_OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logFormFactory().Show();
}
```

В таком виде должно заработать. Библиотека Autofac сама сгенерирует вам для `logFormFactory` функцию которая делает `Resolve` для формы, а каждый `ILogger` со всеми своими зависимостями окажется в дочернем скоупе.

Только не забудьте зарегистрировать `LogForm` как компонент с временем жизни `InstancePerDependency` (это время жизни по умолчанию) - иначе вы будете получать один и тот же экземпляр формы каждый раз при вызове фабрики, а ILogger - как компонент со временем жизни `InstancePerLifetimeScope` - иначе он не будет привязан к LifetimeScope и не будет освобожден при вызове `Dispose()`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73390/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-c-winforms-di-autofac--).